# Slider dissapears in phone/tablet version

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site built with a theme in which the slider dissappears when you open on phone or Tablet. I've tried several different slider plugins, I tried deactivating all plugins and installing all of them one by one, but the problem persists, so I think that it is a PHP problem with the theme, but I can't seem to find a solution for it. When opening on phones or tablet the slider seems to load but it suddenly dissapears but the rest of the page is still there, I think it might take users to a new page when they open it from phones. Anyone could help me out, please?
Thank you!

http://www.lapinatasd.com

Thank you so much!

```html
<?php /* Template Name: Home Page */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <!-- BEGIN HOME SLIDER SECTION -->
    <section id="home-slider">

<?php putRevSlider( 'home' ); ?>


       
    </section>
    <!-- END HOME SLIDER SECTION -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $back = $post //backup post data?>
<?php $child_sections = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' =>'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); ?>
<?php while ($child_sections->have_posts() ) : $child_sections->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $bg = rwmb_meta( '_jellythemes_section_bg', 'type=image', get_the_ID() );  foreach ($bg as $bg_image) : $bg_url = $bg_image['full_url']; endforeach; ?>
    <?php $bg2 = rwmb_meta( '_jellythemes_section_bg2', 'type=image', get_the_ID() );  foreach ($bg2 as $bg_image2) : $bg_url2 = $bg_image2['full_url']; endforeach; ?>
    <?php $video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_parallax_video', true ); ?>
    <?php if (empty($video)): ?>
        <section id="<?php echo esc_attr($post->post_name); ?>" class="section <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_section_type', true ); ?> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_section_color', true ); ?>" style="background-color:<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_bg_color', true ); ?>; <?php echo (!empty($bg_url) ? 'background-image: url(' . $bg_url . ')' . (!empty($bg_url2) ? ', url(' . $bg_url2 . ')' : '') . ';'  : ''); ?>">
            <div class="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_section_width', true ); ?>">
                <?php the_content(); ?> 
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php else: ?>
        <section id="<?php echo esc_attr($post->post_name); ?>" class="player section" data-property="{videoURL:'<?php echo esc_js($video); ?>',containment:'self',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0,opacity:1,ratio:'4/3', addRaster:true}">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <?php $logos = rwmb_meta('_jellythemes_bg_logo', 'type=image', $post->ID ); ?>
            <?php foreach ($logos as $logo) : ?>
            <img class="video-img" src="<?php echo esc_url($logo['full_url']); ?>" alt="video">
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </section>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php $bg_url=''; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $post = $back //restore post data?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using some responsive theme and the area you are using is configured to be hidden on small screen devices. For example, when using bootstrap, there is class hidden-sm-down. Check if this class is applied to the container you are working in. This will make the div invisible in small and xtra-small devices. Refer to [enter link description here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

For better help us understand the issue, attach the HTML of the page as well.

Comment: Hi @vishwakarma09  I tried adding the HTML code here but it's too long, if you use google chrome you can take a look at it by going to view-source:www.lapinatasd.com - I agree with you I think there must be some class hiding it on small screen devices but I can't seem to find it anywhere :( Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: there are 2 sliders - one for about and another for food. I loaded page in chrome by emulating as galaxy s3, the two sliders seem to load